# My Site - When does "My Newsfeed" get refreshed?

Tags: my-site

Which timer job is resposible for refreshing "My Newsfeed"? I am not sure if it is the User Profile Activity Feeds or Search Crawl. Can someone please point me to a technet/msdn article explaining when "My Colleagues" and "My Interests" under My Newsfeeds get refreshed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

User Profile Service – Activity Feed Job

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ee620541.aspx#section11

By default it should be hourly

[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/spses/social-computing-part-3-activity-feeds-social-ratings-tags-and-notes)